# Android File shortened/truncated

Tags: android, file, encryption, aes

I want to create an encrypted file with a magic number in its first character.
If I encrypt the file, everything goes fine, but if I write the magic number first, then the encrypted part is shortened.

I use a .txt file for testing.

This is my code:

```
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(file)
        [...]
        //Write magic number
        fos.write("%AES".getBytes(),0,4);
        byte[] ivbytes = new byte[]{(byte)'a', (byte)'b', (byte)'c', (byte)'d', (byte)'e', (byte)'f', (byte)'g', (byte)'h', (byte)'i', (byte)'j', (byte)'k', (byte)'l', (byte)'m', (byte)'n', (byte)'o', (byte)'p'};
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(ivbytes);
        while(pwd.length()<16) {
            pwd+="_";
        }
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(pwd.getBytes(), "AES");
        // Create cipher
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CFB8/NoPadding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks,iv);
        // Wrap the output stream
        CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);
        while((k = fis.read(d)) > 0)
        {
            cos.write(d, 0, k);
        }
        // Flush and close streams.
        cos.flush();
        cos.close();
        fis.close();
        [...]
```

this is the hexadecimal content [missing byte](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSW8M.png)

debugging is the same with that offset of 4, but when it's time for the last read, the result is turuncated.

i try to encrypt the file, then use a second one with magic number follow by a byte to byte copy, but nothing it always the same.

for debugging i create a text file with the sequence "1234567890"
i obtain this two hexadecimal
[with and without magicNumber](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSW8M.png)

one return the correct sequence, the otherone return "0123456"

Comment: Debug, look at k and the written file in hex, find the difference.

Comment: the difference is the size of what i put in front as magic number which is cutted, even the size of the created file is the same as the original.

Comment: Where is `fis` created?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the data being read by `fis.read(d)` is missing the last four bytes.

Where is `fis` created and how? Watch `k` and `d` in the `while((k = fis.read(d)) > 0)` loop.  The problem is not the encryption it is reading the correct input.

Comment: fis is declared with this line:

FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(file);

and file is a parameter;

k read 55 time 8 byte, the last read (the number 56) read 6 byte with value 115, 117,101,46,13,10,105, 105, the last two won't be write for the write signature, but even using write(byte[] ) is useless.

Comment: Add additional information to the question, a comment like this is really hard to understand. A complete question really helps, see: [mcve].